# How to deal with imbalance datasets for target variable?

Tags: r

Currently I am facing a problem to predict numbers of goals made(soccer) with an imbalance data (760 obs * 129 variables), Target variable - `FTHG`- Full time home goals with

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6 -count of goals made
 175 243 176 107  43  10   6 -- total times of goals made respectively
```

My objective is convert it into majority(1) and minority(0) into binary class, to perform sampling techniques and further use `XGBoost`.

Could anyone let me know how to convert it into binary class majority and minority to perform sampling smot techniques.